# meshgrid changing max values

Tags: python, numpy

If I have

```
min_E, max_E  = (-1335000.0, -1190000.0)
min_N, max_N  = (2255000.0, 2405000.0)
```

And I want to make a meshgrid:

```
res = 1000
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(min_E, max_E, res), np.arange(min_N, max_N, res))
```

why is `yy.max() != max_N`?

```
max_N
Out[27]: 2405000.0

yy.max()
Out[28]: 2404000.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) generates values in `[start, stop)`, i.e. `start <= x < end`, replicating the `range` builtin.  that said, due to floating point precision even this can appear to do "the wrong thing"

I'd suggest using using [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) instead, it's much more convenient for floating point/numeric ranges